# Mavericks style finder list view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm looking for a way to make an NSTableView look like Finder's List View on Mavericks.
I'm mainly after the selection highlight and table header style.

I tried building a sample project against the OS X 10.9 SDK and setting the table view's selection highlight style using 
`setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular` and `setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList` but all I get is the same old < 10.9 styling.

Is there any API call I'm not aware of that can switch the table view to this new style or is Apple drawing it manually?

Comment: Are you actually running it on Mavericks?

Comment: I see nothing related to highlight style listed on the 10.9 API Diffs page (look for `NSTableView.h`): https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/AppKit.html

Comment: @JeremyP: yes, I'm running Mavericks.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I've seen the docs but like you mentioned there's no change regarding the highlight styling. The question is, is there a way to get the same style without manually doing all the work? Maybe when Mavericks is released?

Comment: I would have thought not; I doubt there will be (m)any more API changes now.